# Regular expression problem

Tags: regex

I am having problem with regular expression. I am using regex in query shown as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM ad
WHERE platform_specific_selection
REGEXP '[\|]{0,1}19[\|]{0,1}'
```

It gives me somewhat wrong result shown as below.

1. `19|21|`
2. `0|19|20|22|`
3. `19|`
4. `0|919|`

I wanted to match exact `19` using regex and I don't want `0|919|` this value in result. Can anybody give me exact regex for the same?

Comment: Might I suggest using [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)? You can paste in your data, then play around with your data and see what's selecting live.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
select * from t where a REGEXP '(^|[|])19([|]|$)';
```

(The idea is to allow either `|` or start-of-string on the left, and `|` or end-of-string on the right.)

Answer (score 0):

Why regex, LIKE is sufficient for this

```
SELECT *
FROM ad
WHERE platform_specific_selection
LIKE '%|19|%'
```

Comment: That won't match `19|...` or `...|19`.